# Display elevation in leaflet

Tags: maps, leaflet, elevation

Currently I am exporting a DEM using Agisoft as a TIF.  From here is it possible to display a elevation model in leaflet or are there other steps required?

Answer (score 2):

If your TIF files are already split into tiles, then you next step is a tile server. Often these are created as web services, and you can use a web server such as Apache, IIS, or you can easily roll your own in .NET or Ruby, etc.

Your tile server will provide tiles (images chopped up into an evenly-spaced grid, often `256px x 256px`, but it could be whatever) based on a tile request which often looks something like this: `http://tileserver/tiles/elevation/z/x/y`

You can create a Leaflet base layer of your elevation tiles using JavaScript (which could be hosted on the same web server, or another). Here is a simple example that does so for a USGS elevation data source. It also demonstrates how you can customize tile layer options such as the tile size and the min & max zooms.

```js
var mapElemId = 'map';
var mapOptions = {
  center: [48.699864, -113.802159],
  zoom: 9
};
var map = L.map(mapElemId, mapOptions);
var tileUrl = 'http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';
var tileOptions = {
  tileSize: 256, // 256 is default
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: 'Tiles Courtesy <a href="http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer" target="_blank">USGS</a>'
};
L.tileLayer(tileUrl, tileOptions).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

If you do not already have tiles, you can create them using a variety of methods and programs. Here is one example that is a good description of the process: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs-part-1.html

And another good reference for creating your own tiles from OpenStreetMaps: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles

If you need help with the specifics just let me know!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,  I've actually already got my RGB tif split into tiles and leaflet working correctly.  What I wanted to do with my DEM tif was make an elevation map that for example showed all pixels above the the height of 100m were colored light blue, 75m-99m would be green, etc...  I am just unsure of how I should go about doing that

Comment: With maps you typically display stuff as either a base layer (map tiles) or an overlay (vector features, point/icon features). So which do you want? If you want high resolution (lots of discrete points) it sounds like you want to generate a type of heat map where the "heat" color is the elevation value in meters, which is typically done on the server as a base tile because doing it as a vector requires the browser to generate and update SVG elements as user pans/zooms the map, which can get a bit slow for high density information.

Comment: your example doesn't seem to work, do kindly correct it if possible

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira I updated the outdated CDN URLs - thanks!